# disabling the Ctrl+N and File->New options on browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard-shortcuts

How do you disable the Ctrl+N/File->New options from browser windows, specifically for IE.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? Probably a browser add-in would do the job...

Comment: This is related to duplicate sessions problems I'm facing every time users open (Ctrl-n/File->New) window of an existing session. This will be a temporary fix while we address the bigger problem with session duplication.

Comment: Wouldn't the referrer be empty in that case? You could redirect the page to about:blank or a warning message if you don't want the user to have your web app open in multiple windows.

Comment: Can't do.  You'll need to fix your session handling stuff ASAP.  PS do you have the same issue in IE7 when they open new tabs?

Comment: What about one FF window, one Chrome window, an IE window and an Opera window all viewing the same page?

Answer (score 2):

How much control do you have over the clients?

If you're just serving a page publicly on the WWW, then there's no way.

If you're running a kiosk or a classroom of computers or something, then you could probably hack something together to watch for instances of IE, and disable the menus and trap the Ctrl+N key combination.

Comment: I'm serving a page publicly on WWW

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you are trying to fix the symptom and not the problem itself. The approach you are hinting at is likely to be of limited use (only works in certain browsers) anyway.

I suggest you post the details of your duplicate session problem and let us take a crack at that.

Comment: I don't know that we have bad code that's causing the duplicate session problem. It's just that when you open a new window, the users are working with another instance of the same session from the first window and therefore data is overwritten if they save anything in the new window. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I get that. My point is that you should fix your app to handle the situation gracefully instead of trying to stop the user from doing something that is useful to them. 

Without knowing the details it is hard to make suggestions, but let me take a shot anyway. Have you considered saving the state information for this page in the page itself instead of using session objects to do the dirty work? That could fix the underlying problem instead of the symptom.